# Why bevels on a <90º edge are egg shaped, and not circular?

Tags: mesh, geometry, bevel

If you make a bevel on an edge that is sharper than 90º, it won't be circular.
This is what i have to do in order to make a circular bevel on a sharp edge:

1. Make a 1 segment bevel
2. On the resulting 2 edges, make bevels that meat each other.
3. Weld the part where the 2 bevels meet.

[image: circular bevel]

But if I would make just a single bevel, it will look like this:

[image: egg shaped bevel]

Why is it like that? And is there a solution less convoluted than what I've shown? Recommended add-on perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried clicking through each of the 4 offset methods? Offset, Width, Depth, and Percent? Adjusting the Profile slider? Using a custom profile?

Comment: Yes. I played with all the other settings, too. The 2nd closest i got to the desired effect is by adjusting profile %. But it still results in ugly geometry: [image](https://i.imgur.com/iWVYzMC.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working on current version. (2.91.0)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this problem, but it is easily fixed by simply applying the scale with "ctrl-A > scale".

Comment: If you look at his second picture, the scale is (1,1,1) meaning it is already applied.